# Nested foreach in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockout.js

I can't seem to get a nested foreach to work.

JS code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function chartValueViewModel(date, price) {
        this.date = date;
        this.price = price;
    }

    function chartViewModel(id, name, lineType, values) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.lineType = lineType;
        this.values = ko.observableArray(values);
    }

    function liveCurveViewModel() {

        this.chartsData = ko.observableArray([]);
        var chartsData = this.chartsData;

        this.init = function() {

            var mappedCharts = $.map(chartValues,
            function(chart) {
                var mappedValues = $.map(chart.chartValues, function(value) {
                    return new chartValueViewModel(value.dateTime, value.price);
                })
                return new chartViewModel(chart.id, chart.name, chart.liveCurveTypeId, mappedValues);
            });

            chartsData(mappedCharts);
        };
    }

    var vm = new liveCurveViewModel();
    vm.init();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

Html is:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: chartsData ">
    <li data-bind="text: name">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: values">
           <li data-bind="text: price">
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The outside loop renders correctly, but I get nothing from the inside loop, not even an error message. I've checked and the values field on the chartViewModel is populated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `text` binding that you have on your outside `li` is overwriting the content inside of it, so it is blowing away your inner `foreach`. The `text` binding sets the innerText/textContent of the element, which overwrites the current children.

You would want to do something like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: chartsData ">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: values">
           <li data-bind="text: price">
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RP Niemeyer u should explain why outer li text binding overwrite the inner one. if possible explain this behavior in details. thanks

Comment: @Thomas - added an additional sentence to clarify that the `text` binding sets innertText/textContent. Hope that helps!